# Reduce lines, use case?

Tags: delphi, case

How to reduce the lines, I could use `case`? I feel that this code is too large, no way to improve?

```
      if valmes.Text = '01' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '0';
      if valmes.Text = '02' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '1';
      if valmes.Text = '03' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '2';
      if valmes.Text = '04' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '3';
      if valmes.Text = '05' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '4';
      if valmes.Text = '06' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '5';
      if valmes.Text = '07' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '6';
      if valmes.Text = '08' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '7';
      if valmes.Text = '09' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '8';
      if valmes.Text = '10' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '9';
      if valmes.Text = '11' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '10';
      if valmes.Text = '12' then
      WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '11';
```

ex:

```
case AnsiIndexStr(valmes.text, ['11', '12']) of
0: WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := '10';
```

Comment: why do you use TEdit to choose month ? cannot you just use a list ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a simple way to improve the code:

```
var
  ix: Integer;
...
ix := StrToInt(valmes.Text);
WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expmonth', 0).value := IntToStr(ix-1);
```

You can add some sanity checks using `if TryStrToInt(valmes.Text,ix) then ...`.

Comment: It worked perfectly, but as I do in this case.
          if valano.Text = '15' then
          WebTesta.OleObject.Document.all.Item('expyear', 0).value := '0';

Comment: @RegisSantos So add some code to handle error cases

Comment: @RegisSantos I agree with David Heffernan. You need to add additional validation code to prevent that. Even more you need to add additional validation code when your edit may not contain string representing numerical value. BTW next time when you are using bucnh of if statements one after another as you did in your code I strongly suggest you make use of if...else if...else statement. Why? In your case every separate if statement will be checking if its condition is met. But with if...else if once condition of one matches all the rest are simply skipped.